# Move and Resize Subplots in Octave

Tags: resize, octave, subplot

I'd like to move and resize four subplots in Octave so that they are bigger with less white space between them. The minimal code below only moves and resizes the first subplot (221) whilst leaving the remaining three untouched.

```
sp_hand1 = subplot(221);plot(sinewave(20,20)) ;
set( sp_hand1 , 'OuterPosition' , [ -0.11 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.65 ] ) ;

sp_hand2 = subplot(222);plot(sinewave(20,20)) ;
set( sp_hand2 , 'OuterPosition' , [ -0.11 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.65 ] ) ;

sp_hand3 = subplot(223);plot(sinewave(20,20)) ;
set( sp_hand3 , 'OuterPosition' , [ -0.11 , 0 , 0.6 , 0.65 ] ) ;

sp_hand4 = subplot(224);plot(sinewave(20,20)) ;
set( sp_hand4 , 'OuterPosition' , [ -0.11 , 0 , 0.6 , 0.65 ] ) ;
```

How can I resize them all to be the same size and moved appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I faced a similar issue during my thesis, I found that the solution that worked best for me was to use `axes` directly rather than subplots, and specify `position`. Some manual adjustment may be unavoidable in the beginning, but it's typically pretty straightforward, and can be automated easily for predictable graph placements, especially if the figure size is pre-specified too.

E.g.

```
h1 = axes('position', [0.04, 0.54, 0.45, 0.45]); plot( sinewave( 20, 20 ) );
h2 = axes('position', [0.54, 0.54, 0.45, 0.45]); plot( sinewave( 20, 20 ) );
h3 = axes('position', [0.04, 0.04, 0.45, 0.45]); plot( sinewave( 20, 20 ) );
h4 = axes('position', [0.54, 0.04, 0.45, 0.45]); plot( sinewave( 20, 20 ) );
```

In theory subplots and independent axes should behave more or less the same; the big difference being that in case of overlap, subplot deletes the overlapped plot, whereas axes overlaps happily. This would include 'invisible' overlaps.

I am not 100% sure if there is a way to obtain the same result using 'outerposition', but for me outerposition tends to behave a bit oddly, and I've always managed to get the desired results with 'position' directly, so I've never had a need for it.

I have also found that often plotting more things or changing other aspects of the plot resets some axes properties, so such size adjustments are best done as the last step for each axes object.